# VS 2022 HoloLens 2 Deploy error: DEP0600: Deployment failed. Failed to deploy through new deployment pipeline

Tags: c++, uwp, icons, visual-studio-2022, hololens

I am using VS2022 and HoloLens 2 with native C++ code using the Microsoft Sample for Holographic Remoting from GitHub. I made the modifications I wanted and all is working well. I decided to change the icons and other normal UWP png files to something for my project. I modified the graphic that ultimately becomes the icon on the App Start button (also referred to as the "launcher".) While I could change all the other graphics, this one causes a deploy error. I cannot find any reason why this should cause a DEP0600.

The problem gets worse! In an effort to fix the icon image, I decided to use the UWP graphics generator that can be found by opening the package.appxmanifest in VS then using the Visual Assets tab. I thought it might generate an acceptable icon png file. NO! This created a bunch of new graphics and added an Assets folder to the project and failed to deploy. I manually removed all the added files and folder. I restored my package manifest, removed all the added stuff from the vcproj file. Still no joy, deployment error.

**Fix for DEP0600:** I removed my IP address trying to force a reset of some kind. Nothing worked. After exhausting every solution, I could find short of reimaging, I did find a solution to the DEP0600. **Remove the paring from the HoloLens to VS**. Note when you unpair on HoloLens it unpairs everything, meaning you will have to pair again with other devices as needed.

**Root Problem:**
All that said, the DEP0600 can be fixed. But **I still have the root cause problem**, how to construct a png file that can be used with a HoloLens 2 UWP. Specifically, this configuration: Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png

Obviously, creating this has rules that are not readily available in the documentation. Any help on this and pointers to documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the icon assets in the HoloLens project, you can refer to [Submitting an app to the Microsoft Store - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/distribute/submitting-an-app-to-the-microsoft-store#prepare-image-assets-included-in-the-appx). The HoloLens app is also a UWP app, so usually you can also automatically generate them through the [Asset Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/iconography/visual-studio-asset-generation) in Visual Studio. Now that you have fixed DEP0600, you can try Asset Generator again, or share the error it caused.

Comment: @zuocheng-wang-msft, I have not tried your suggestions yet instead have simply ignored the issue as it is not a high priority work item. When we start the UA tests it will come up again, I'm sure.